# Calling a php script from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scripting

I have a server side PHP script which connects to a database and selects some data. This works in a separate browser but I can't seem to get it to run from a script in HTML.

My code is as follows:

```
   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <script>
   function myFunction() 
    {
 $.ajax({
    $.post("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/test.php")
    .done(function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
  }
  </script>
  <body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Sites</button>
  </body>
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't run"? For starters drop the `$.ajax({ ... });`. `$.post` is short-hand for `$.ajax`.

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Your code is syntactically invalid.

Comment: So my server side php runs in a seperate browser and give me output but when i try to embed it in the java script i get no output.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this page http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
ajax() and post() are two different functions and your use of them is wrong.
You have 2 possibilities :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: //here your script's url
    data: //here the data you want to send
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
    //data is the server answer
    });
$.post( yoururl,yourdata)
.done(function( data ) {
// data is the server answer
});
```

Comment: How is it wrong? How can the OP fix it? Help the OP. Delete if no longer relevant.

Comment: What's the op ?  I can't see your problem

Comment: OP: "Original Poster" (the person who posted the question). I'm asking you to be more verbose in your answer. Explain *how* his "use of them is wrong". It's not enough just to say the OP is wrong. Also include an example of how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
function myFunction() 
{
  $.post( "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/test.php", function( data ) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
}
```

Comment: How does this help the OP? Your suggested method is actually being [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object). OP's use of `.done()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

the circle of ajax

HTML code

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" value="5" id="id">
<span id="total"></span>
</form>
```

jquery code

```
$(function(){
    $('#form').change(function(){
        var id= $('#form #id').val(); // get value

        $.post("ajax/your_php_file.php",id:id},function(data){
                if(data.error=="OK"){ 
                    $('#total').empty().append(data.total);
                } else { 
                       alert(data.erreur);
                }
        },"json");
        return false;
    })
});
```

php file

```
require_once('conection.php'); // if you need a conection to database
$data = array(); // to put data inside this array
extract($_POST); // to convert a $_POST to a normal varible 
    if(isset($id) AND $id>0) { 
             $data['total']=7; //... your code
             $data['error']='OK';
    } else { 
       $data['error']="no id!";
    }
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I hope this is helpful in guiding the OP to the answer, but you are making **a lot** of assumptions.